# Fragment Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I read [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer#setup-drawer-in-activity.) post :

I try to do it but i have trouble in the "Navigating between Menu Items" section.

Where do the code of this section go ? In the MainActivity.java file or else?

When i paste it on my `IDE` (Android Studio 1.4) the items "nvDrawer" and "NavigationView" are red:

Also, i have two `onCreate()` on the same file.

Can you give me some suggestions how to make it work?

Below the code of my MainActivity.java.

```
package com.ther01s.android.ma0;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Make sure this is the method with just `Bundle` as the signature
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Find our drawer view
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
                break;

            default:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }


}
```

Comment: Install latest android studio . then go to File --> New Project-->Configure your Project-->Target Device-->Choose Navigation Drawer Activity--> finish.  You will get an awesome template from Android studio itself. Dont be confused by looking up for other useless tutorials.

Comment: @Rubin Its was great! I manage to make it works by folowing your advice. Thks Rubin

Comment: Happy to hear that. i had added it as an answer . if it helped you please mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install latest android studio . then go to `File --> New Project-->Configure your Project-->Target Device-->Choose Navigation Drawer Activity--> finish`.  You will get an awesome template from Android studio itself. Dont be confused by looking up for other useless tutorials.